# Launching IE and Chrome browser using Capybara, Selenium, Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I am new to Cucumber and Capybara. I am trying to launch IE and Chrome browser.
I have downloaded drivers of both and copied them to bin folder of Ruby in C drive.
I have set Path in Env var.
Below is my support/env.rb file code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Capybara.run_server = false
#Set default driver as Selenium
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
#Set default selector as css
Capybara.default_selector = :css

#Syncronization related settings
module Helpers
  def without_resynchronize
    page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = false
    yield
    page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = true
  end
end
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => chrome)  #Getting error at this line
end
World(Capybara::DSL, Helpers)
```

I am getting compilation Error at line with comment is as below.

> method calls where the number of arguments passed to the method does not match the number of method parameters.

Here is my environment:

cucumber (2.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.0.3)
capybara (2.11.0)
rspec (3.5.0)
Ruby 2.3

Answer (score 0):

`Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => chrome)` try changing it to `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)`

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried with this option you suggested. Still I am facing same issue as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi, I have tested with same configuration (except Ruby version) on my machine and its's working.

Comment: can you try with this:  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|